# Create a column based on meeting a condition in 2 as.Date columns in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

In my df I have 2 columns:

"date of covid test" &
"date of death"

Both columns have A LOT of NAs.
And it can happen that someone passed away and never had a covid test or someone had a covid test but never passed away.
Example:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","345","567","79"),
                 date_of_covid_test = c(2020-04-02, NA, NA, 2020-11-03, NA, 2020-12-05),
                 date_of_death = c(2020-05-03, 2000-03-01, 2000-01-01, NA, NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to create an extra column based on this sentence:

"If date of death happens AFTER date of covid test = yes, otherwise = no"

**The expected output would be:** that only patient 3454 would be TRUE and all the others would be FALSE.

Basically **the point** is to know **whether the death happened after the covid test**, that would be a TRUE. Alternatively would be a FALSE.

I hope this makes sense

What is the right way of coding this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show few lines of data and expected output for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure your columns are in date format you can try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    condition = ifelse(date_of_covid_test < date_of_death, "yes", "no")
  )
```

where `df` is your dataframe and `date_of_covid_test` and `date_of_death` are the column names of the dataframe.

It works, but make sure the dates behave correctly!

Comment: Thank you! I would like to create this in a new column. How could I do?

Comment: `dplyr`'s `mutate` command creates a new column in your dataframe. 
Have you tested the code I posted?